# Visual studio for c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have installed visual studio express 2010 c++. However when trying to follow a beginners book and make the hello world program, visual studio opens up a project with this in it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
return 0;
}
```

The thing is, this looks nothing like the c++ in the book i have just started reading (C++ Without Fear). In fact, if i type 'cout',even after entering using namespace std, cout is not found.

This is the books example:

```
                      #include "stdafx.h" 
                      #include <iostream> 
                      using namespace std; 

                      int main() { 
                              cout << "Never fear, C++ is here!"; 
                               return 0; 
                       }
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alex said start with C++ Win32 console project, but select empty project so that the IDE don't fill things out automatically! Go to Source Files in your Solution Explorer, right click on it and add new item and choose C++ file (call it main.cpp for example).

At that point you should be ready to go.

Try this sample code that I prepared for you...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(char *argv[], int argc) {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It should print out Hello World! in the console.

Answer (score 5):

Create Windows (or Win32, don't remember exactly) C++ Console Application project, don't select C++/CLI project type.

C++/CLI is very special language, which is used only for interoperability between managed and unmanaged code. It is better to forget about C+++/CLI at this stage...

Comment: Agreed.  If you do a console application the code will be very similar to your textbook in all likliness.  Chances are the auto-generated main will look a little funny to you, but you can replace it with a normal int main() {} right away - aside from that you should be good :)  It'll also include that stdafx.h, just ignore it and program as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You want to start with a Visual C++ Win32 Console Application.

If you want to create your own files completely (i.e. no stub file with a main defined), you can check "Empty Project" in the options of the Win32 Application Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

This is not C++. This is so called "managed" C++. Basically, a totally different language by Microsoft that is compatible with their .NET platform. For example, you can mix C# code and managed C++ code in single binary. This technology is very Microsoft specific and is not portable to any other compiler/OS (even Mono, which is C# for Linux, doesn't have it). See [Managed Extensions for C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C++) for more details.

Comment: It seems vs express 2010 can't handle the non managed c++ then? Even if i select win32 console application, it doesn't understand using namespace std; it says std is not found.

Comment: You also need to #include <iostream>

Comment: @Daniel: It certainly does. You have to have necessary includes as Joe have pointed out.